# Calculated column with hyperlink to open items in modal works only on the 1st page of list view

Tags: 2013, list-view, calculated-column, modal-dialog

In SharePoint 2013 I have a Site page with list view web part that contains calculated column. In this column the following function is executed to be able to open items in modal:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("a.viewItem").each(function() {
    var headerid = $(this).parent().parent().parent("tr").attr("iid").split(",")[1]
    var href = "URL"+headerid;
    console.log(href);
    var onlink = "openInDialog(500,500,true,true,true,'"+ href +"&IsDlg=1');"
    $(this).attr('onclick', onlink);
});
```

});

Unfortunately, this works only on the first page of list view. If 2nd page is opened (next 30 items), the script is not executed.

How can I fix this so that it works for all list items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  use the following CSR script in a JS file and attach it as JSLink to the list view webpart(under `Advanced` properties)

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{

    var linkFunction = function ()
    {
        $("a.viewItem").each(function ()
        {
            var headerid = $(this).parent().parent().parent("tr").attr("iid").split(",")[1]
                var href = "URL" + headerid;
            console.log(href);
            var onlink = "openInDialog(500,500,true,true,true,'" + href + "&IsDlg=1');"
                $(this).attr('onclick', onlink);
        }
        );
    } // close linkFunction

    SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function ()
    {
        linkFunction();
        SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(
        {
            OnPreRender: function (ctx)
            {
                linkFunction();
            }, // close OnPreRender
            OnPostRender: function (ctx)
            {
                linkFunction();
            } // close OnPostRender
        }
        ); // close RegisterTemplateOverrides

    }
    ); // close executeFunc

}
); // close ready
```

Here `OnPreRender` and `OnPostRender` will execute when ever you do a sort, filter and move to another page in the list view making sure the events are attached to the required objects.

This [page](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views) helped me in designing CSR codes like above and explaind how OnPreRender and OnPostRender works.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now links are opening from other pages too. 

Is there a way how to solve the following issue –
Currently when I click on the link from second page and an item is opened in modal, in the background list view returns back to first page ?